# Match domain and extension of two email addresses in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with email addresses. Some emails have sub-domains, and others don't. I need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` these tables based on the domain name and extension, while ignoring any sub-domains and anything left of the @ symbol.

| Contacts.Contact | Managers.Manager |
| --- | --- |
| bob@api.ibm.com | sarah@ibm.com |
| jim@sales.ibm.com | jane@mgt.yahoo.ca |
| joe@ibm.com | fred@google.com |
| zoe@yahoo.com | sam@facebook.co.uk |
| elf@api.yahoo.ca |  |
| frank@yahoo.ca |  |
| jack@oracle.com |  |

```sql
SELECT Contact.Contact, 
       Managers.Manager 
FROM Contact 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Manager ON ???
```

should yield the following results:

| Field: Contact | Field: Manager |
| --- | --- |
| bob@api.ibm.com | sarah@ibm.com |
| jim@sales.ibm.com | sarah@ibm.com |
| joe@ibm.com | sarah@ibm.com |
| zoe@yahoo.com |  |
| elf@api.yahoo.ca | jane@mgt.yahoo.ca |
| frank@yahoo.ca | jane@mgt.yahoo.ca |
| jack@oracle.com |  |

The `ibm.com` and `yahoo.ca` emails were matched. So basically, the pattern is: `IGNORE@IF_THIS_EXISTS_THEN_IGNORE.MATCH.MATCH` Is this possible? If it is, then what is the correct SELECT statement to yield these results? Thanks.

Comment: LEFT JOIN, to also get contacts with no matching manager e-mail.

Comment: so all of co.uk is treated the same?  that seems very wrong

Comment: Thankfully, I'm only working with single dot domain extensions. But you are correct that this strategy won't work for multi-dot extensions like .co.uk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the (at most) two domain parts on the right, just do:

```
substring_index(substring_index(email,'@',-1),'.',-2)
```

Apply that to both Contact and Manager and join on the results being equal.